# LaTeXで"含まれる"を表す波括弧を表現するには？

Tags: latex, 数学

LaTeXを使って「有理数、無理数は実数に含まれる」という形を波括弧を使って表したいと考えています。

つまり以下のアスキーアートを画像のような形で表したいのですが、都合よく左大波括弧だけを出力する方法がわからず悩んでいます。

```
 　   /　有理数
実数 -|
 　   \　無理数
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 試してみたこと

[【LaTeX】括弧類のかき方一覧と大きさの変更方法まとめ](https://mathlandscape.com/latex-bracket/) を参考に

```latex
実数\biggm {
有理数\\
無理数\\
```

と感覚で試してみましたが効果なしで、同じ試みをしているページも見つからず、途方に暮れています。

まとめると

- 有理数、無理数のような2項が1つの集合に含まれるという意味で波括弧を使いたい

お時間をいただき感謝します。

Comment: [Conditional equations with with one curly bracket in LaTex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288108)

Answer (score 2):

以下ページの一覧にある「｛ による場合わけ表示」が当てはまりそうです。

[http://www1.kiy.jp/~yoka/LaTeX/latex.html](http://www1.kiy.jp/%7Eyoka/LaTeX/latex.html)

> 記述例:
>
> ```
> \begin{equation}
> f(x)= \left \{
> \begin{array}{l}
> 1　(x＝1のとき) \\
> 0　(x≠1のとき)
> \end{array}
> \right.
> \end{equation}
> ```
>
> 表示例:
> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません。ご提案の方法を試した結果、無事解決いたしました。本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: お役に立てたようで何よりです。解決した場合にはこの回答を [承認] してもらえると助かります。参考ヘルプ: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

一番簡単なのは、`amsmath`パッケージの`cases`環境を使うことだと思われます。

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
      x & \text{if $x \ge 0$}, \\
    - x & \text{if $x < 0 $}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

`\biggm`など`m`付き（middleの頭文字でしょう）のコマンドは、関係演算子用のものです。具体的な利用例としては、集合の内包表記や条件付き確率を表す際の`\mid`等に前置するケースが挙げられます。ご質問の場合わけの大きな開きブレースは、あくまで開きカッコ類なので`l`付きのコマンドを用いるか、`\left`による自動制御を用いるのが正しいと思います。cubickさんの回答にあるように、実際には開きカッコ類のみを印字して、閉じカッコ類を出力しない場合は、`\right`に続けてドット`.`を打つことになっています。

---

`\left\{` / `\right.`による方法とamsmathのcases環境を使う方法がすでに示されていますが、網羅性のため別解としてcasesパッケージが提供するnumcases環境を使う方法も示しておきます。

```latex
\documentclass{jsarticle}
\usepackage{cases}
\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}{|a| =}
a & （$a\geq 0$のとき） \\
-a & （$a<0$のとき）
\end{numcases}

\end{document}
```

cases環境と違い、numcasesでは場合わけの各行に個別の式番号が付与されます。また、各行の条件部（`&`より後ろ）は非数式のテキストとして扱われる点に注意してください。

[image: numcases環境を使用した場合の出力例]